# Authentication with iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a very simple question, I have a node.js/express server that will handle backend authentication part, it is using token not cookies, the server part is working correctly, whenever someone register/login it would return with a JSON web token.

For example:

```
{
    "token" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdW"
}
```

I'm using Alamofire to handle the HTTP request from iOS itself. The real question lies is how do I persist the token in the iOS/Swift itself?

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You can keep it in variable, `NSUserDefaults` or core data... I think you already knew that, so can you clarify your question.

Comment: gave you the anwser :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the iOS Keychain to save sensitive information.

You should **not** use `NSUserDefaults` to store an authentication token or any other potentially sensitive information. It's unencrypted and easily accessible on a rooted device.

How would you like someone getting your authentication token and making requests to your private API at will (e.g. on the command line using  `curl`)?

I've used the [KeychainAccess](https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeychainAccess) CocoaPod and its usage is simple:

```
static let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.example.myapp")
keychain["secret_code"] = secretCode     // Save something
let secretCode = keychain["secret_code"] // Retrieve something
```

Comment: I managed to get it working, but right now I have one last question, how do i decrypt the token on the IOS side?

Comment: In my answer, the second line encrypts and the third line decrypts.

Comment: Don't mind, I already figure it out, basically just need to use Alamofire with authorization settings

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to store it in `NSUserDefaults` like this:

**Writing:**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Your Variable Value", forKey: "token")
```

**Reading:**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let token = defaults.stringForKey("token") {
    print(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be `NSUserDefaults`, but the most secure way would be to store the token in the iOS Keychain. Note there are several wrapper libraries ([for example](https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift)) available to make working with the keychain easier in Swift. The API can be a bit intimidating at times.

Comment: Plenty, but unfortunately I'm laying in a hospital bed for a few days.  Check out this project for a Swift keychain wrapper designed to make it easier to store text within the keychain - https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift

Comment: Owh man, sorry for asking, get well soon. I found another library https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess , you think it is better?

Comment: It looks like a pretty good choice, too.  The code seems pretty straightforward.